# JComponent size issue

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, paintcomponent

I have a `JComponent` subclass that I am using to draw shapes onto my screen. In the constructor, I am trying to set `ballX` and `ballY` to half of the *X* and *Y* size values of the `JComponent`, and I think I am doing it wrong. I have looked this up a lot now, and cannot find a remedy. The code is as follows. Please bear in mind that this is my first real Swing/Graphics2D venture.

```
public class PongCanvas extends JComponent {
//Vars to hold XY values and Dimension values.

    private int batXDim, batYDim;
    private int b1X, b1Y;
    private int b2X, b2Y;
    private int ballRad, ballX, ballY;

    public PongCanvas() {//Instantiate vars.
        batXDim = 20;
        batYDim = 100;

        b1X = 0;
        b1Y = 0;

        b2X = 0;
        b2Y = 0;

        ballRad = 20;
        ballX = getWidth() / 2;
        ballY = getHeight() / 2;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {//Main paint Method.
        //Cast Graphics to Graphics2D.
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        //Enable antialiasing.
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        //Draw background.
        g2.setPaint(Color.black);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        //Draw ball.
        g2.setPaint(Color.white);
        g2.fillOval(ballX, ballY, ballRad, ballRad);
        //Draw bat 1.
        g2.fillRect(b1X, b1Y, batXDim, batYDim);
        //Draw bat 2.
        g2.fillRect(b2X, b2Y, batXDim, batYDim);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override [`getPreferredSize()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize%28%29) in your `JComponent` to return your preferred size, and start with half the width and height of that `Dimension`. To the same end, this [`KineticModel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel) invokes `setPreferredSize()` in [`DisplayPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel/code#DisplayPanel).

Addendum: By way of explanation, your current approach fails because the results from `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` are *invalid* until  `validate()` has been called on the enclosing container, typically as the result of [`pack()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: Update your example by overriding the two methods, `paintComponent()` and `getPreferredSize()`. The annotation `@Override` will prove helpful.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I shall make the changes once my dev machine is up and running again (keep getting kernel panics).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with trashgod's answer. (+1)

Move the ballX and ballY in the `paintComponent(g)` like this

```
if (ballX==0 && ballY==0) {
    ballX = getWidth()/2;
    ballY = getHeight()/2;
}
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value). Of course, `(0,0)` then becomes the entrance to a kind of wormhole! I often use `Point p;` and later check `if (p == null)` to initialize the starting point.