# Java PaintComponent size and position in a subclass of an abstract class that extends Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, class, abstract, paintcomponent

I'm building a simple chess game and am stuck on trying to paint drawings on a Panel

I have a board ready and on the board there are panels. those panels are 70x70px and next thing i want to do is use THAT ENTIRE SURFACE to draw chess pieces.

i made an abstract class Pieces that extends JPanel.

```
public abstract class Piece extends JPanel
```

One of the pieces is ofcourse, a Pawn :

```
public class Pawn extends Piece
```

in the Pawn class I have paint component :

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(0, 0, w, h);
    System.out.println("height:"+h+" width:"+w);
}
```

This does not seem to work. the output prints height = 10px and width = 10px; .... but it is suposed to be 70px and 70px. I also see the green oval painted inside a 10x10 square, which is inside my Panel...

I tried a setSize(70,70) which does not realy do the trick... 
I also tried SetPreferredSize but well It did not really work out either. 
I really want to keep my abstract class and subclasses...

@@@ EDIT @@@
I've used setPreferredSize again and I can now actually draw my green circle on the Jpanel. but an error remains as in it is not the whole surface of the Jpanel Used... there remains a gap at the top , a screenshot:
 [image: http://imgur.com/INVj4]

Comment: Your issue is that you are attempting to output a 70x70px image into a 10x10 canvas, please include more code so that we can see what you are attempting to draw on.

Comment: Don't use setSize(). Override the setPreferredSize() method to reurn the Dimension(70, 70).

Comment: I did that but an error remains as it seems to have a padding/margin at the top which i cant get removed

Comment: Probably because you are using a FlowLayout which have 5 pixels of horizontal/vertical spacing between components. If you need more help post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I solved this problem by deleting setpreferredsize in all and adding a layout manager inside my Jpanel, which i did not do before... works perfectly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- if you only to set `Background` to `Color.GREEN` then extends `JComponent`,
- if you want to add only [Image](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) then look for Icon in [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), note `JLabel` is transparent, `non-opaque` by default,
- any [JComponent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) can returns `setXxxSize`,
- not all [LayoutManagers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) accepted `setXxxSize`,

example [JComponent with setXxxSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759992/set-maximum-size-of-jpanel-inside-borderlayout-center/7760310#7760310)

Comment: +1 See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017561/jcomponent-size-issue/8017763#8017763).